# Howto force Report Viewer to be shown in print preview mode

Tags: visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, reportviewer, rdlc

In Visual Studio 2005, how can I show a report in ReportViewer control directly on Print-preview mode?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `SetDisplayMode()` method:

```
MyReportViewer.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms application if you call the SetDisplayMode method in reportviewer's RenderingComplete event it may cause StackOverflowException. It is not correct place to call the method.